# Question about intermediate value theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis

I have slight issue in the proof below. I don't understand why $c + \frac{1}{n} < b$. This is from Terence Tao Analysis 1.  [image: introduction to proof]

[image: proof part that I am having problems with]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c<b$ means $0<b-c$. By the Archimedean principle, there is a natural $N$ such that $\frac1n<b-c$, which is to say $c+\frac1n<b$, whenever $n> N$.

Note that we choose an $N$ specifically so that it is large enough for this to work. It is not the case that we pick an $N$ at some earlier stage, and then just assume that the inequality holds.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon=b-c$.

It is clear that $ \epsilon>0$ since $c\in(a,b)$.

Now, using the fact that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac 1n=0$, we can say that

$$(\exists N\in \Bbb N)\;:\;(\forall n>N)\; \frac 1n<b-c$$

or

$$(\exists N\in\Bbb N)\;:\;(\forall n>N)\;c+\frac 1n<b$$